# I wrote a code that animates an Eulerian cycle on a graph but something is missing

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This code here

```
Euleriano[g_] :=
 l = {FindEulerianCycle[g][[1]][[1]][[1]]} For[i = 1, 
    i < EdgeCount[g] + 1, i++, 
    AppendTo[l, 
     FindEulerianCycle[g][[1]][[i]][[2]]]] Block[{grafo = g, inizio, 
     cammino}, inizio = FindEulerianCycle[grafo][[1]][[1]][[1]];
    cammino = l;
    ListAnimate[
     Table[Graph[grafo, 
       VertexStyle -> 
        Append[Map[Rule[#, Pink] &, Union[cammino[[1 ;; v]]]], 
         cammino[[v]] -> Red], 
       EdgeStyle -> 
        Evaluate[(UndirectedEdge[#1, #2] -> Directive[Red, Thick]) & @@@
           Partition[cammino[[1 ;; v]], 2, 1]], 
       VertexSize -> Medium], {v, Length[cammino]}]]]
```

finds and animates an eulerian cycle on an input graph, provided it has one. The problem is this animation always misses the last edge of the cycle. How can I solve this?
For clarification, cammino=path, inizio=start, grafo=graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing some typo in your code. It seems to run fine to me:

This code here

```
Euleriano[g_] :=
 (l = {FindEulerianCycle[g][[1]][[1]][[1]]}; For[i = 1, 
    i < EdgeCount[g] + 1, i++, 
    AppendTo[l, 
     FindEulerianCycle[g][[1]][[i]][[2]]]] Block[{grafo = g, inizio, 
     cammino}, inizio = FindEulerianCycle[grafo][[1]][[1]][[1]];
    cammino = l;
    ListAnimate[
     Table[Graph[grafo, 
       VertexStyle -> 
        Append[Map[Rule[#, Pink] &, Union[cammino[[1 ;; v]]]], 
         cammino[[v]] -> Red], 
       EdgeStyle -> 
        Evaluate[(UndirectedEdge[#1, #2] -> Directive[Red, Thick]) & @@@
           Partition[cammino[[1 ;; v]], 2, 1]], 
       VertexSize -> Medium], {v, Length[cammino]}]]])
```

You could also use Animate and HighlightGraph for simpler code:

```
AnimateEulerican[g_] :=
 With[{l = First[FindEulerianCycle[g]]},    
  Animate[HighlightGraph[
    g, {Style[Graph[l[[1 ;; n]]], Directive[Pink, Thick]], 
     Style[l[[n, 2]], Red]}, VertexSize -> {_ -> Medium}], {n, 1, 
    Length[l], 1}]]
```